# Asp.Net General Local Resource tool for user control

Tags: asp.net, localization

When I use the Visual Studio menu Tool -> Generate Local Resource, it changed aspx file by adding meta attributes to controls. But it doesnt do so for user controls that I have created.

For example, If I have used a control in the page

```
<myControl:SpecialLabelControl ID="myLabel" runat="server" Text="Localize Me!" />
```

I want "Localize Me!" to go in the resource file and a meta attribute added to the SpecialLabelControl.

How can I do this?

How does the tool create resource strings for built in controls automatically? Does it read an attribute of the property? How can I make the tool do the same to my control?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, make sure 'Text' is a publicly accessible property on your control.

Add [Localizable(true)] above the declaration, as shown in the example on [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.localizableattribute.aspx)

This will tell the IDE that this property is supposed to be picked up by resource files, and Tools -> Generate Local Resources will do the rest!
EDIT - after further research I came across [this article](http://web.archive.org/web/20090306193410/http://www.dotnet2themax.com/blogs/mbellinaso/PermaLink,guid,2ca72726-2047-470d-a8af-4e535b061708.aspx) (and excerpt from a book).  It seems that UserControls you created with publicly accessible properties can't be hit by the GLR tool :(

The ones I've worked on before were classes I created as '.cs' files, not user controls, I suppose.

Answer (score 0):

Add it manually into the resource file as:

```
myLabel.Text
```

Then change the control to:

```
<myControl:SpecialLabelControl ID="myLabel" runat="server" meta:resourceKey="LiteralIdentifyBody" />
```

Comment: Yes, thats what I am doing now. But how does the tool create resource strings fro built in controls automatically? Does it read an attribute of the property? How can I make the tool do the same to my control?

Comment: Ah, sorry, I misunderstood your question, it might be using the DefaultProperty attribute.